# Why does yield call(response.json) hang?

Tags: redux, redux-saga, yield

```
const response = yield call(fetch, `${config.backendUrl}/verify`, {
  method: 'POST'
})

const responseJson = yield call(response.json)

console.log(responseJson)
```

This is code from redux-saga. Yield hangs and `console.log` does not print anything. But if I replace `response.json` with `() => response.json()` it works. Why?

Comment: Perhaps `call` is passing arguments that cause `response.json` to act differently. Try `(...args) => { console.log(args); response.json() }` to see what they are

Comment: `args` appear to be empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you invoke `yield call(response.json)` the `response.json` is called with wrong context (`this`).

You could fix this with `bind` (e.g. `yield call(response.json.bind(response))`), or by specifying `context` (e.g. `yield call([response, response.json])`), but `call` here is really useless. You can just:

```
const responseJson = yield response.json();
```